# Doing two different batch queries and a delete query in one transaction (Java)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ejb-3.1

I want to ask about the best way of optimizing these three queries.
This function is going to be used by millions of users in a national project and I want it to be as optimized(fast) as possible.

Please add any helpful comment or answer :) 
and thank you in advance.

```
 try {
    //so we don't execute empty batches
    boolean flag=false;
    conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    autoCommitValue = conn.getAutoCommit();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE input = ?");
    stmt.setLong(1, input);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
    stmt = conn
            .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table1 (c1)  values (?)");

    for (Object Info : Info List) {
        if (Info .getType() == 0) {
            flag=true;
            stmt.setInt(1, Info.getC1());
            stmt.addBatch();
        }
    }
    if(flag){
    result = stmt.executeBatch();
    flag=false;
    }
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table1 (c1,c2,c3) values (?,?,?)");

    for (Object Info : Info List) {
        if (Info .getType() != 0) {
            flag=true;
            stmt.setLong(1, input);
            stmt.setInt(2, Info.getC1());
            stmt.setInt(3, resInfo.getC2());
            stmt.addBatch();
         }
    }
    if(flag){
    result = stmt.executeBatch();
    }
    conn.commit();

} catch (SQLException e) {
     conn.rollback();
    throw new SQLException();
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        // now we return the connection to its original state
        conn.setAutoCommit(autoCommitValue);
    }
    closeDBObjects(conn, stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do, before trying to optimize the code, is to make it compiling. The following lines don't compile:

```
for (Object Info : Info List) {
    if (Info .getType() != 0) {
    ...
```

Then I would make the code cleaner by respecting the Java naming conventions, by splitting this long method in several ones, and by using better names than `flag`, for example.

Then I would measure, test and see if I have a performance problem. And if I have one, I would try to find where it comes from. And only if I'm sure that it comes from this method (which is unlikely), then I would try to optimize it.

Let's suppose this method needs to be optimized. The first thing I would do is to make sure that the appropriate index exists, to speed up the delete statement.

Then I would avoid preparing the two statements if the list is empty. You avoid their execution using the flag variable, but you don't avoid their preparation.

Then I would try to see if using a batch is necessary, or if using several ones is useful, depending on the size of the list, on what my database recommends, and on what the measurements and tests say.

But as I said. Doing all this is premature optimization, which is the root of all evil. Try to make the code correct, clean and maintainable before.

Comment: I am really sorry about the naming and the mistakes in the code I copied my original code and had to 'mask' it. 
I think I am going to choose this as my accepted answer because you mentioned something new to me which is "premature optimization".

Thank you JB Nizet :)